# C++ std::function-like template syntax

Tags: templates, c++11, syntax, variadic-templates, std-function

In C++11 you can instantiate std::function like this:

```
std::function<void(int)> f1;
std::function<int(std::string, std::string)> f2;
//and so on
```

But while there is plenty of info on variadic templates on the web, I fail to find any articles on how to write std::function-like template which would accept parenthesized arguments.
Could anyone please explain the syntax and its limitations or at least point to an existing explanation?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's nothing special about it, it's an ordinary function type. When you declare a function like this:

```
int foo(char a, double b)
```

Then its type is `int (char, double)`. One way of "unwrapping" the individual argument types and return type is to use partial template specialisation. Basically, `std::function` looks something like this:

```
template <class T>
struct function; // not defined

template <class R, class... A>
struct function<R (A...)>
{
  // definition here
};
```

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, int(char, double) is interpreted as a single function type, but we can then extract return type and parameter list with partial specialization?

Comment: @Cynic Yes, that's exactly how it works. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I need syntax like `template <typename F> void foo(F(int) intCallable){...}` :/

Comment: @MariuszJaskółka The syntax for that is `foo(F intCallable(int))`. It's just like any other function syntax: the name comes between the return type and the argument list.

Answer (score 6):

Pretty much like any other template, since `int(std::string, std::string)` is just a type.

Here's a really naive example that compiles:

```
template <typename FType>
struct Functor
{
   Functor(FType* fptr) : fptr(fptr) {}

   template <typename ...Args>
   void call(Args... args)
   {
      fptr(args...);
   }

private:
   FType* fptr;
};

void foo(int x, char y, bool z) {}

int main()
{
   Functor<void(int, char, bool)> f(&foo);
   f.call(1, 'a', true);
   //f.call(); // error: too few arguments to function
}
```

In reality you'd have a specialisation on `FType` being `ReturnType(ArgTypes...)`, though my naive example will already give you the validation you need if you try to invoke it in in compatible ways.